# Get a Users Featured Video with Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to get a users featured video ID from a feed.

This may be a bug in the YouTube API as seen here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/z0x1vmjTsP4

Anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is still broken. I just pinged the internal bug again.